# Grep line by length but if does not contain char

Tags: bash, grep

I need to grep a line by it's length `grep '.\{80\}' -B 1 file` but only if it does not contain a special char `>`.

My file looks like

```
>asdf1
xxxxx
>asdf2
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

and it should be decided on the `xxxx` length if the line + the one above make it through the filter. The line with '>' shall be simply ignored for the calculation.

The expected output should be a file containing the pair of the upper line and line of xxxxx that are longer than 20.

Comment: Better to extend your question and advise what is the expected output...

Comment: better? @GeorgeVasillou

Comment: My 2 cents: Rather than describing output, it is better to show the actual expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Check this test out . Seems to be what you are looking for:

```
$ echo "$f1"
>asdf
xxxxxxxxxx
>asdf
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>bcde
xxxxx
>ghtr
xxxx
>qwer
xxxxxx

$ grep '^[^>].\{4\}$' -B1 <(echo "$f1") #exactly 5 chars
>bcde
xxxxx

$ grep '^[^>].\{8,\}$' -B1 <(echo "$f1") #9 chars and longer
>asdf
xxxxxxxxxx
>asdf
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

So in your case and according to your comments this will bring you lines with exactly 20 chars:

```
$ grep '^[^>].\{19\}$' -B1 file
```

Or for longer than 20:

```
$ grep '^[^>].\{19,\}$' -B1 file
```

Comment: @Eldude Something like this ?

Answer (score 1):

It is spectacularly unclear what you are actually asking for, put perhaps something as simple as:

```
awk '/^>/ {a=$0;next} length($0) > 20{print a RS $0}' input
```